# SQL Editor features usually existing in an IDE?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm a fan of dbeaver user, but i miss the features that are usually existing in a modern java IDE, such as finding references, navigating codes, refactoring:

1. Autocompletes db view columns
2. Find references for a table -- the db views making use of this table
3. Find references for a table col -- the db views making use of this table col
4. Find references for a view -- the db views making use of this view
5. Find references for a view col -- the db views making use of this view col
6. When reading a view, I can easily click a shortcut like F3 to navigate to the table, or table col, or to another view used in that view based on the cursor position
7. A keyboard shortcut to go back and forth after a navigation action is performed. For example, when reading a view, my cursor goes to a table name, i F3 to jump to table definition, alt+leftArrow to 'navigate' back to the previous view and cursor position.
8. Refactoring into a sql migration file. For example, changing a column name of a table of a view might affect other views, or tables, and the collection of statements to achieve this could be exported to an sql file that can be migrated to our db.

Any pointers on your the sql editor[s] that might having the aforementioned features ? I'm currently using postgres exclusively.